# Knockout JS Validation for Date of Birth less than 18

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

Need help in building a function for my Project which will disable anybody from entering the date of birth less than 18 in the date of birth field.

A validation will work !! just need help in building a validation

htmlcode

```
<label>Date of Birth <span class="red-asterisk">*</span></label>
<input type="text" id="DOB" name="DateOfBirth" placeholder="&nbsp dd/mm/yyyy" data-bind="datePicker : Model.DateOfBirth, dateTimePickerOptions : {format: 'DD/MM/YYYY', maxDate: (new Date()).addDays(-6573), useCurrent : false}" />
```

js file code

```
self.Model.DateOfBirth = ko.observable().extend({
    date: true,
    required: {
        params: true,
        message: "Please enter a date"
    }
});
```

where shall I change the code for validation or showing a validation age less than 18 years old not allowed to sign in?

Comment: Have you seen [this example](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules#min-age) from the docs?

Comment: I tried it doesn't help much !! :( can you please help me again...

Comment: There are a couple ways of doing so, you can either opt for disabling the input field or else implement the extender functionality and then use that implementation. It is very simple and easy to implement the [extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create knockout custom rule as follows

```
ko.validation.rules["DateValidation"] = {
    validator: function (val) {
       var ageDifMs = Date.now() - val.getTime();
       var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
       var year = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
       return (year < 18);
    },
    message: " "
};

ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

then you can add to your extend

```
self.Model.DateOfBirth = ko.observable().extend({
date: true,
required: {
    params: true,
    message: "Please enter a date"
},
DateValidation: {
     message: "Override message"
            }
 });
```

Comment: Will you please elaborate more what code should i right starting from todays date to validate that at present the person in 18years and older

Comment: ko.validation.rules["DateValidation"] = {
        validator: function (val)
        {
            if (Year>=2000) {                
                alert('Date Validated 18 Years and Above');
                return true;
            }
            // custom logic for date check and return true or false
           
            else
            {
                
            }
        },
        message: " "
    };